# PHP: sessions not consistent between directories

Tags: php, session

EDIT:
I tested this on a different server with what I would expect: the session followed between directories. This is either a PHP or Apache configuration issue.

I also looked at php.net. There are ways to affect setcookie()'s path, but I don't see something similar with session_start().

```
****Original Post****
```

File 1: public_html/one_up/session_test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['testing'] = 'Yup';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [testing] => Yup )
```

File 2: public_html/session_test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Output:

```
Array ()
```

Is there a configuration I'm not aware of? This is on a dedicated server with default configurations as far as I know. I'm the only one that has changed anything.

Comment: do you transmit cookies via cookies or via GET URLs?

Comment: How arer you linking form `one_up/session_test.php` to `session_test.php` ??? visiting them differently or using hyperlinks

Comment: Same browser typing directly into the address bar. I've also tried linking, but when that didn't work, I decided to eliminate all variables. that's when these files got created.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say how do you transmit session id: session.use_cookies in php.conf

Comment: Check your browser to see what the directory restrictions are on your session cookies. Your server may be setting it wrong, making each directory level get its own session.

Comment: What do you mean by "Check your browser". Is this information contained in the cookie? I'll check. The session vars are server-side though aside from the ID. Oh! I should echo the session_id();

Comment: @j13r: I understood what you meant. It's not in GET.

Comment: Same session_id. Chrome indicates the path of the cookie is /. Not sure if that's helpful.

Comment: increase the error level and run the examples in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the session config directives [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).
Try a `phpinfo()` in different folders to debug.

Use a function call like `ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp/eggs');` to override the directives.

Comment: That did fix it. I went with /tmp since it was using that anyway.